# The rails way : where to place code that explores some websites and retrieve data every 10 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the rails way(The best way, or let's say state of the art) to place a piece of code that do a certain task every x minutes.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this kind of code in the `lib/tasks` folder. After all it is a task that is running from time to time.

Obs.: There is no right place, just put it where it feels right.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by writing task in lib/tasks. And then write job to run that task on every 10 minutes.